# Uncaught Error: useNavigate() may be used only in the context of a <Router> component [react-router-dom 6.4]

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

For the last couple of hours, I'm trying to figure this out, but no success. This works perfectly fine with react-router-dom 6.3, but as soon as I upgrade to any 6.4 version, I get mentioned error. I already checked, and all my imports are from 'react-router-dom',

The Orders component does contain useNavigate(), but as you can see, HashRouter is the highest it can be. This is my simplified index.tsx and it still does not work.

```
const container = document.getElementById('root');
if (container) {
  const root = createRoot(container);
  root.render(
    <React.StrictMode>
      <HashRouter>
        <Provider store={store}>
          <ChakraProvider theme={theme}>
            <Routes>
              <Route path='/' element={<Orders />} />
            </Routes>
          </ChakraProvider>
        </Provider>
      </HashRouter>
    </React.StrictMode>,
  );
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Remove both provider and then try.

Comment: I don't see any issue with *this* specific code. RRDv6.4 really only introduced the Data APIs, it didn't change how the regular routers work much at all. Can you edit the post to include a complete [mcve]?

Answer (score 0):

No idea why, but switching to ViteJs from CRA fixed the problem.